# STORM CRAWLER : Generate cookie from a separate link via basic authentication and use the cookie to crawl the links in seeds.txt

Tags: cookies, forms-authentication, apache-storm, stormcrawler

The website that I want to crawl is enabled with an authentication via a third party basic authentication. For example, the url that needs to be crawled is https://intranet.crawl.com
The url first gets redirected to another page : http://auth.intranet.com, that allows a basic authentication, on passing the valid username and password it uses the cookie to login to https://intranet.crawl.com

How can I achieve the above authentication in storm crawler?

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to use Selenium and have a custom NavigationFilter to fill the credentials on the redirected URL, see [tutorial](http://digitalpebble.blogspot.co.uk/2017/04/crawl-dynamic-content-with-selenium-and.html).

You could also generate the cookie externally prior to the crawling and specify it in the seed metadata [using the key set-cookie](https://github.com/DigitalPebble/storm-crawler/blob/master/core/src/main/java/com/digitalpebble/stormcrawler/protocol/httpclient/HttpProtocol.java#L84). You'd need to add that key to *metadata.transfer* in your conf so that it gets transmitted to the outlinks and persisted to the storage.

Comment: Thanks Julien . I am pretty new to storm, can you please elaborate a bit more?

Are you saying that we can write a custom program that would hit the redirected url, provide basic authentication and capture the cookie.

But how do you pass this cookie to the urls mentioned in the seeds.txt? This cookie generated is valid for a maximum of 30 minutes (expiry), how do we trigger to regenerate the cookie?

Comment: you don't need a custom program, you can just use curl on the authentication URL with the user password and retrieve the cookies returned. You then specify the cookies in the metadata transfer of the seed.